# cannot get screen command to execute code containing DISPLAY=:0

Tags: shell-script, ssh, environment-variables, gnu-screen, remote

I am trying to ssh into a remote machine and run a shell script, which opens a GUI.  I want the GUI to open on the remote machine and remain open (so I am using `DISPLAY=:0 nohup`).  I tried:

```
ssh -t <user-name>@<remote-host> "DISPLAY=:0 nohup ~/<script-to-be-run>.sh"
```

This worked great, but I can't send another command without closing the window because the GUI called in the shell script ties up the command line.  I tried using `"DISPLAY=:0 nohup ~/<script-to-be-run>.sh &"` and `"DISPLAY=:0 nohup ~/<script-to-be-run>.sh && exit"`, but these produce the same result: the GUI opens and the command line is left hanging.

I read about using `screen` to detach the command from the shell session, but this doesn't seem to work.  On the remote machine (NOT running through ssh, just sitting in front of it), I tried:

```
screen -m -S 'test' 'DISPLAY=:0 nohup ~/<script-to-be-run>.sh'
```

but I get an error:

`Cannot exec 'DISPLAY=:0 nohup ~/<script-to-be-run>.sh':No such file or directory`.

The command `DISPLAY=:0 nohup ~/<script-to-be-run>.sh` works just fine when run on the remote machine (while sitting in front of it).  Anyone know how to get this command to work with `screen` so that I can run the single GUI command in its own terminal container?

Answer (score 2):

Normally, `screen` accepts a command and arguments, so this might work:

```
screen -m -S 'test' nohup ~/<script-to-be-run>.sh
```

Because it is not expecting a variable assignment, and the variable might otherwise be reset, you would probably have to add `env` to set the variable:

```
screen -m -S 'test' env DISPLAY=:0 nohup ~/<script-to-be-run>.sh'
```